# Extracting urls with querystring from a html

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to extract urls with querystring from the following html, using regex, but it nos working. Could you help me out, please?

What I am trying to match: https://www.joinville.sc.gov.br/jornal/visualizaranexos?cod_jornal=755&cod_sei_publicacao=529

**1.1 My regex:**

```
(?<=href=").*?\?.*?(?=")
```

**1.2 Output of this regex**

```
https://www.joinville.sc.gov.br/public/portaladm/pdf/jornal/ed1301f83021029837bd0628e8e98d39.pdf\" target=\"_blank\"> <span class=\"thumb-jornal\"> <img src=\"/public/portal/imagens/ico_diario.png\" class=\"jornal-icon\" width=\"46\" height=\"38\" alt=\"\"> <span class=\"jornal-shadow\"></span> </span> </a> <span class=\"article-date bolder\"> <span class=\"article-subject\">ano 2016</span> <img src=\"/public/portal/imagens/arrow-bullet.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"11\" class=\"arrow-bullet\" alt=\">\">n° 398  - <a rel=\"shadowbox;width=500;height=400\" href=\"https://www.joinville.sc.gov.br/jornal/visualizaranexos?cod_jornal=755&cod_sei_publicacao=529"
```

**2. Html:**

```
<li> <a href="https://www.joinville.sc.gov.br/public/portaladm/pdf/jornal/ed1301f83021029837bd0628e8e98d39.pdf" target="_blank"> <span class="thumb-jornal"> <img src="/public/portal/imagens/ico_diario.png" class="jornal-icon" width="46" height="38" alt=""> <span class="jornal-shadow"></span> </span> </a> <span class="article-date bolder"> <span class="article-subject">ano 2016</span> <img src="/public/portal/imagens/arrow-bullet.gif" width="8" height="11" class="arrow-bullet" alt=">">n° 398  - <a rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=400" href="https://www.joinville.sc.gov.br/jornal/visualizaranexos?cod_jornal=755&cod_sei_publicacao=529" style="font-size: 8px; display: inline; color: #ff0000;">anexos</a> </span> <span class="article-date">19/02/2016</span> </li>
```

Edit: the following regex looks like it is working ->  (?<=href=")[^"]+\?[^"]+(?=")

Comment: Why -1? please, expain

Comment: Why is the output of this regex (1.2 above) wrong? You have to explain exactly what you want the regex to output in order for people to help.

Comment: Specify what type of url you are trying to match.

Comment: @KatyaHandler  sorry, will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get that right you're only interested in URLs with parameters? Then I think this does the trick.

```
(?<=href=")([\S\?]*\?.*?)(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
href="([^"]+)"
```

The first capture group is the URL you are looking for. [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/iR5hI5/1)